# Pushing wrong repo to github

Tags: git, github

I have been trying to push a new project to my GitHub and the wrong repo gets pushed to GitHub.

I have created a new project in my folder with this command:

```
npx create-expo-app my-app
```

My app gets created successfully and then I go to GitHub and create a new repository, one that is done I am presented with this:

[image]

So then I write in my terminal:

```
cd desktop
cd dev
cd my-app

git remote add origin https://github.com/nicolelopezfeliz/TEST.git
git branch -M main
git push -u origin main
```

when I write my GitHub commands and I push the commit to my repo I get the wrong repo in my GitHub. My first commit then becomes this:
[image]

I have now pushed up my entire desktop on GitHub. The repo that is now on remote add origin https://github.com/nicolelopezfeliz/TEST.git (called HorseBet) is a project in which I had pushed up last week and I ran an yarn eject in it - does that affect my coming repos?

What I have tried:

- I have tried to create a new folder in my desktop and created the project there and followed the same steps but I got the same outcome
- I also tried to run:

```
git remote remove origin
```

everywhere to remove the origins but I got the same outcome.

- I tried to name my project differently, both on my computer but also in my GitHub - got the same outcome.
- I deleted the HorseBet project and re-followed the steps mentioned above but got the same outcome.

Comment: Where did you run `git init`?

Comment: I ran git init inside the project folder

Comment: Apparently you have already initialized a git repository in the parent directory of `Desktop`.